# Geocoder Geocode - Google Maps javascript API

Tags: javascript, maps, undefined, geocode

I have a problem with the below function:

```
function geo(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            return results[0].geometry.location;
        }
    });
}
```

It returns me "undefined". Any help would be approciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your geocoding code is correct. The problem is that "geocoder.geocode" is asynchronous, and the geo function finishes execution before the geocoding result is fetched. As a proof of concept just try this:

```
function geo(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            alert(results[0].geometry.location); //should have valid info
            return results[0].geometry.location;                    
        }
    });

    alert("I bet you were not expecting this alert to go first");                
}
```

So, you have two options. Either you handle the geocoding location inside the geo function or you supply a callback with the function that will handle the location.

I've updated your fiddle with an example of this. Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rqwAF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks.

I found other solution - It's better to save a value from results[0].geometry.location to cookie and use wherever I want. Thanks anyway!